# Design Huge Integer Class

Tags: java

I am designing a class called HugeInteger - which uses 40 element array of digits to store integers. I am providing a method called parse in which it receive a String, extract each digit as shown in the snippet below. also I am providing method add which it receives an object of class HugeInteger to do the addition.
The method provided for the add is not working as proposed and I would like you if you could help me in a solution.
P.S I noticed some similar questions asked before but it did not help me.

```
private int [] integerDigits = new int[SIZE];

//constructor that enables an object of class to be initialised when it is declared
    public HugeInteger(String stringOfIntegers)
    {
        setOfIntegers = stringOfIntegers;
    }//end of constructor

private int[] parseFunction (String str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                integerDigits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            else
                    integerDigits[i] = 0;
        }   
                return integerDigits;
        }//end of method parseFunction

    public HugeInteger addFunction(HugeInteger number)
        {
            parseFunction(setOfIntegers);
            return new HugeInteger(setOfIntegers +number.parseFunction(setOfIntegers));
        }//end of method addFunction
```

Comment: `The method provided for the add is not working as proposed`... how?

Comment: Is this homework, or is there some other reason you don't like `BigInteger`?

Comment: @Louise, It is a homework because I am studying Java on my own currently.

Comment: @Talnicolas, The add method should add have the ability to add accept 2 strings after parsing them and get the addition result.

Comment: What is your question? You appear to be storing digits and assuming that all you numbers with be 40 digits long. You don't appear to support negative numbers.

Comment: @Peter, you are right!!! I am not supporting negative values at the moment as I am doing a top down design and I am considering to solve the problem bit by bit.

Comment: Where does `setOfIntegers` come from? Is it an instance field? What is its type?

Comment: I suspect you need to fix your parseFunction first, but I don't see any code in addFunction which would add all the digits together. I suggest you step through your code in a debugger because it doesn't do what the code suggests.

Comment: @natix, setOfIntegers is an instance field of Private String type.

Comment: @Peter, you are quite right, that why I am in here for !! someone to guide to solve the addition method.

Comment: Does your code actually compile? If yes, please post the whole code of your HugeInteger class.

Comment: You need to solve the parsing problem first, add a unit test.  You can't meaningfully add until you have numbers to add.  Then create a test to add two number together and write a loop which adds each digit.

Comment: @Peter, what software shall I used to debug the code? I am using Eclipse to execute codes. thank you for your time and help Peter.

Comment: Not all method names have to end with "Function".

Comment: The debug button is next to the run button.  There are no functions in Java, only methods. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter and Griffey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in this line here:

```
return new HugeInteger(setOfIntegers +number.parseFunction(setOfIntegers));
```

Because setOfIntegers is a String, the + symbol doesn't mean addition but concatenation for them (writing them back to back). Thus when adding 5 and 6 you would get 56 instead of 11.
Instead of calling the constructor you need to implement the addition like you would do it on paper, from the back to the front, using a variable to hold the carry number.

Example:

```
    99
+   11
     0 carry 1
    10 carry 1
=  110
```

Additionally, because you always use 40 digits and you start at the front of the array, there is no way for your problem to know how much of theses digits really belong to the number so that it cannot differentiate between "5", "500", "5000" and so on. This is a problem because parseFunction(5)=parseFunction(50)={5,0,0,0,...,0} (39 zeroes all in all) and the problem cannot know how to align the numbers. It would be better to loop downwards ("integerDigits[40-i]= Character.getNumericValue(ch);") because then "5" would become 0000....05 and "50" would become 000050.

Another small error is

```
number.parseFunction(setOfIntegers)
```

which should be

```
number.parseFunction(number.setOfIntegers)
```

Comment: Thank you Kirdie for your input - it is highly appreciated.